# pillar data in orchestration sls files are not resolved

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using Salt 2018.3.2 with following pillar data in /srv/pillar/mypillar.sls

```
#!yaml
mypillar:
  some_key: some_value
```

and try to use it in the following state file /srv/salt/orch/mypillar.sls

```
write-pillar-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/mypillar.txt
    - contents_pillar: mypillar
```

It works fine if called as a state:

> $ salt 'localhost' state.apply orch.mypillar

Yet does not work if called as orchestrate runner:

```
$ salt-run state.orchestrate orch.mypillar
[INFO    ] Loading fresh modules for state activity
[INFO    ] Fetching file from saltenv 'base', ** done ** 'orch/mypillar.sls'
[INFO    ] Running state [/tmp/mypillar.txt] at time 18:32:03.120348
[INFO    ] Executing state file.managed for [/tmp/mypillar.txt]
[ERROR   ] Pillar mypillar does not exist
[INFO    ] Completed state [/tmp/mypillar.txt] at time 18:32:03.122809 (duration_in_ms=2.461)
```

It works if I pass the pillar via commandline, but I want to access the pillar from the filesystem. Shouldn't this be possible?
Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on [github](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/49489) and got the advice that pillar information is tied to minions, which means that salt-run has no access to pillar info as it runs without minion context.
A workaround is to explicitly query the pillar information like this (in my example I've used 'localhost' as minion ID of my salt master):

```
{% set pillardata = salt.saltutil.runner('pillar.show_pillar', kwarg={'minion': 'localhost'}) %}

write-pillar-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/mypillar.txt
    - contents:
      - {{ pillardata['mypillar']['some_key'] }}
```

Comment: This is just annoying. I mean, your workaround is great, but it's just one of the _many_ workarounds salt requires. There are so many choices they've made having no sense whatsoever. Getting data from pillars should be possible using salt-run without workaround like this. What about formulas? Should I update all of those running in orchestration ? After over a year, this is apparently still the case..